# Cannot declare class Google\Google_Client, because the name is already in use in vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php

Tags: php, composer-php, google-analytics-api

Using this code to access google analytics data but keep on getting the above error

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/autoload.php';
$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
printResults($results);
//use Google_Client;
function initializeAnalytics()
{
$KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
$client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

return $analytics;
}
```

Comment: You have an autoloader, why are you manually doing the require for the google client?

Comment: consider following this.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php

Comment: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Client' not found

Comment: It looks like the `Google_Client` class is located in the `Google` namespace. Thus you either need to add a `use` statement first or use the fully qualified class name.

Comment: Was able to include the Client library in a php file using the same syntax. Either it's not supported in a php class or it has a different syntax than used above.